# Injecting mock initiated by InjectingMock

Tags: mockito

```
    @InjectMocks
    private Foo foo;
    @Mock
    private Var var;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass
```

Foo has Var.
MyClass has Foo.
I am injectiong Var in Foo by `@InjectMocks` and like to inject Foo to MyClass but Foo in MyClass is null.

I guess it's because Foo is not annotated by `@Mock`. Is there any way I can inject Foo to MyClass while injecting Var to Foo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your class dependency is like this:

```
MyClass ---dependsOn--> Foo --dependsOn--> Var
```

If you are writing unit tests for `MyClass`, you just need to mock `Foo` and inject into `MyClass`. Because `Foo` itself is mocked in this case, you don't need to worry about its dependencies.

```
@Mock private Foo foo;
@InjectMock private MyClass myClass;
```

To write unit tests for `Foo`, I'd suggest you create a separate unit test class in a separate file. There you can mock `Var` and inject into `Foo`.

```
@Mock private Var var;
@InjectMock private Foo foo;
```

To conclude, unit tests should be written for each layer of dependencies. You shouldn't mix unit tests of two layers in one test file. To unit test a class, you just need to mock its *direct* dependencies. So while testing `MyClass`, you just mock `Var` and simulate its behaviour as per your requirement:

```
Mockito.when(var.someMethod()).thenReturn(someValue);
```